# How Can I Change product prices on checkout step 4 (After customer choose payment method)?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, products, model, checkout-page

```
public function paymentEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $this->log("Entramos al observer");
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach($cartItems as $item) {
       $productId = $item->getProductId();
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
       $newPrice = $this->getNewPrice($product->getPrice()); // Function that calculate the newPrice (%)
       $product->setPrice($newPrice);
       $this->log($product->getPrice()); // this shows the new price
       $product->save(); // this doesn't save nothing, on step 5 the price is the same.
    }
    $this->log("Observer END");
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to set new price for next order or for current order items?

Comment: Thanks for your time, Yes what i want is this:

    if a customer choose the payment method "**Y**" i will rise the price of the product a 8%, so i need to change the product prices of that customer on his checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function paymentEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $this->log("Entramos al observer");
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach($cartItems as $item) {
      $newPrice = $this->getNewPrice($item->getPrice()); // Function that calculate the newPrice (%)
      $item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);
      $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
      $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
      $item->save();

    }
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    $this->log("Observer END");
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Dude, you r amazing. 

Thanks so much, that's exactly what i need.

Comment: I was testing the method applied and it turns out that if I go back one step at the checkout (from step 5 to 4 ) I still take the previous payment method, I have to go back 2 times and choose the "new method" to take it into account.
____


    Example: first i choose Payment Method Y and works ok, but if for some reason i need to changa the payment method and i go back to step 4 and now i choose payment method Z, all the calculates are made with the payment method Y, i need again to go back to step 4 and choose again Payment Method Z and now it shows the prices ok.

Comment: I'm using this event on my Observer class **sales_quote_payment_import_data_before**.

Comment: @Waskalle I think you have raised new question. Thanks I get to know new thing :)